# How to put an icon and p tag aligned on the same line (materializecss)

Tags: html, css, material-design, materialize

I am using materialize css along with material icons, trying to put an icon and beside that a few numbers, but I don't know how to.
Here is the code:

```
<i class="material-icons">person</i>
<p>123123</p>
```

would be awesome if someone could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this the materialize way, just add a class of left to the icon:

```
<i class="material-icons left">person</i>
<p>123123</p>
```

The documentation for button sheds some light on this - this is where we traditionally see text and icons side by side in the framework.

https://materializecss.com/buttons.html

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="material-icons left">cloud</i>button</a>
```

@927tanmay's answer is technically correct  - the left class just adds float:left to the element - but there's no need to write inline or extra css as the left class is part of the documentation and intended to be used with icons.

See more on the [helpers](https://materializecss.com/helpers.html) section.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code with the following:

```html
<p><i class="material-icons">person</i>123123</p>
```

Comment: I have tried this method and it works, but the icon is slightly towards the up. putting a margin at the top pushes down the whole line

Answer (score 1):

You have to just add "float: left" style property to your icon tag. Try the below code.

```
  <i class="material-icons" style="float:left">person</i>
  <p>123123</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand you very well but I assume that you want to put numbers and icon next to each other so you have to put them inside a div tag then style the div like this:

```
<div style="display:flex;">
   <i class="material-icons">person</i>
   <p>123123</p>
</div>
```

browsers may apply some styles on `<p>` like margin so you have set margin:0 to `<p>` if you need it.

Another way to get same result is setting display property of both `<p>` and `<i>` to `"inline-block"`

Answer (score 1):

## The display property

The Display property is essentially responsible for determining how to layout your elements.

### Display Block

The good old *div* for example has by default a display property of *block*. This means it will fill up the entire available width and every element after is rendered on a *new line*. It also makes sense if you think about the word *block*.

```html
<div>Div's display defaults to block</div>
<div>Div's display defaults to block</div>
```

### Display Inline

Now the other famous tag is *span* which has a display property of *inline*. This will not break onto a *new line*. It also makes sense if we think about the word itself *inline.*

```html
<span>span's display defaults to inline</span>
<span>span's display defaults to inline</span>
```

You see, we have a very basic way of saying I want to be laid out vertically or I want this to be laid out horizontally.

### Other methods

Over the years the demand for more sophisticated ways to layout things rose. Back in the day people would use *float* but that has many drawbacks. Nowadays we have two powerful tools in our CSS toolbox. *Flexbox* and *CSS Grid*.

When using flex box you can think of a single axis that can be used to lay out elements, while CSS grid offer a true 2d space that can be used. I leave it to the reader to explore these more.